# Where Like Active Record query only working when params is a one letter string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, activerecord

So I'm trying to do a basic search form with Rails that should retrieve any records which have a title similar to the query.

In my controller I'm using the following code to perform the search

```
def index
  if params[:search]
    @communities = Community.where("title LIKE :query", query: "%#{params[:search][:query]}%")
  else
    @communities = Community.all.order('created_at DESC')
  end
end
```

Everything works fine if `params[:search][:query]` is a one character string (i.e. the search fetches all communities with a :title containing that one character). However, whenever `params[:search][:query]` is set to a string with more than one character the search fetches an empty `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

What am I missing?

**As requested here's an example of this issue**

When I run the following code in the console:

```
Community.where("title LIKE :query", query: "%#{"oreo"}%")
#=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

But this next one:

```
Community.where("title LIKE :query", query: "%#{"o"}%")
#=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Community id: 2, title: "Oreo Community", welcome_message: nil, social: true, owner_id: 1, created_at: "2017-02-20 08:59:19", updated_at: "2017-02-20 08:59:19"]>
```

Comment: Tell me whether it worked or not

Comment: @Andrew Can you add an example of a string and example of a record you are trying to search for?

Comment: Thanks Slava, I've added an example in the question as you requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, `LIKE` is case sensitive and will not match `oreo` and `Oreo`.

But `ILIKE` is not case sensitive.

So you either need to check with `ILIKE` or downcase the values

```
Community.where("title ILIKE :query", query: "%#{'oreo'}%")
# OR
Community.where("lower(title) LIKE :query", query: "%#{'oreo'}%".downcase)
```

Comment: Deepak, thanks for your answer, the issue is solved now with ILIKE. I'll have it in mind in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 def index
    if params[:search]
      @communities = Community.where("title LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search][:query]}%")
    else
      @communities = Community.all.order('created_at DESC')
    end
  end
```

Comment: thanks Aniket, Sorry forgot to mention I've tried that as well with same results. Still retrieving results when there's a one character string only.

Comment: what are you getting in this variable %#{params[:search][:query]}%. And are you sure it is params[:search][:query] or it should be this params[:search]....

Comment: params[:search][:query] is outputting the string entered in the form field (e.g. "something"). I've tried the AR query in the console adding directly a string and had the same result

Comment: sharing your console result and show your table communities